# MVC Compilation Error, using WebApplication1 in Temporary ASP.NET Files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reference, asp.net-web-api2

I got this wierd error today and I can't solve it, obviously.
I've created an entire ASP.NET API, which works just fine, no trouble. Now I want to add some MVC pages to the application. ASP.NET API automatically gives you one controller, (home controller) with the default asp.net page.

Now when I try to open this page, I browse to http://localhost:26264/home.

First I got the error with System.Web.MVC reference:
`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0...` I solved this by going to nuget manager and update MVC, which updated it to version `5.2.3.0` as stated in my web.config file (below).

Now I get another error when browsing to the same address.
I get a compilation error:

**Description:** An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WebApplication1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 26:     using System.Web.Optimization;
Line 27:     using System.Web.Routing;
Line 28:     using WebApplication1;
Line 29:     
Line 30:
```

`Source File: c:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.t8kfgnmp.0.cs    Line: 28`

1. My application name is *not* WebApplication1 to begin with.
2. Re-building didn't work,
3. deleting the temp folder didn't work.
4. deleting the debug, release and bin folder didn't work.
5. I can't find it anywhere in my references of my project or in my web.config file.
6. Deleting any projects that were not used anymore from the solution.
7. Running it on my laptop, where I never compiled the project, gives the same error.
8. Other, newly created, mvc application do work.

I went through every .cs file and nowhere I've made this using.

Like I said, the rest runs fine, but I can't open any MVC page, even when creating a empty one.

Only thing I can think of is that it should be something with versions, like I got at first with MVC. Because I've downloaded a template for this API from a website (for correct external login behavior in an API). So the project dates from 13-07-2014.

My Web.Config file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework"
      type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="AuthContext"
       connectionString="some database"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <machineKey validationKey="confidential I guess"
      decryptionKey="confidential I guess" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
        preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856sad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\33a25be8\00298484_2fe1cf01\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\e4e456f0\80a7fc09_c7a6d001\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\5e13637a\0064da67_6c98d001\WebGrease.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\556b9ea4\80bf1a60_6c98d001\System.Web.Optimization.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\b004c4ba\00298484_2fe1cf01\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\d053c54a\00298484_2fe1cf01\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\c00cea1f\00298484_2fe1cf01\EntityFramework.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\8a259b50\80a7fc09_c7a6d001\System.Web.Helpers.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\697894d0\80a7fc09_c7a6d001\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\5b891fac\00298484_2fe1cf01\Owin.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\20287057\00298484_2fe1cf01\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\9e3324b2\00298484_2fe1cf01\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\f5e62a40\0037a966_6c98d001\Antlr3.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\df949ad9\00298484_2fe1cf01\System.Web.Http.Owin.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\2de213fd\00298484_2fe1cf01\System.Web.Http.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\b76d5c10\00298484_2fe1cf01\System.Web.Cors.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\e4698f0d\00298484_2fe1cf01\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\42f17822\00db2a40_2c8ed001\Microsoft.Owin.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\492af3ed\80a7fc09_c7a6d001\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\56706741\80a7fc09_c7a6d001\System.Web.WebPages.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\d26ced0e\00db2a40_2c8ed001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\6c6c0552\8071c340_2c8ed001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\bbcc5165\80a7fc09_c7a6d001\System.Web.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\0be6b9ea\00298484_2fe1cf01\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\App_global.asax.wzkby3d1.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\18153ac5\00298484_2fe1cf01\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\96b61974\00298484_2fe1cf01\Microsoft.Owin.Cors.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\995618f0\00db2a40_2c8ed001\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\1742251e\7fa56e65_d0a6d001\AngularJSAuthentication.API.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\06b74cb9\8052b946_2c8ed001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\assembly\dl3\c5202dd8\00298484_2fe1cf01\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll" /out:"C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\App_Web_index.cshtml.6373d792.i9ntk24m.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /warnaserror-  "C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\App_Web_index.cshtml.6373d792.i9ntk24m.0.cs" "C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\App_Web_index.cshtml.6373d792.i9ntk24m.1.cs"


Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.18408

for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\46ca8dc5\51ac0d57\App_Web_index.cshtml.6373d792.i9ntk24m.0.cs(28,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WebApplication1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The source file is a bit long but if it helps:

```
#pragma checksum "[pathToProject]\AngularJSAuthentication\AngularJSAuthentication.API\Views\home\Index.cshtml" "{ff1816ec-a...."
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18444
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace ASP {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Helpers;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.WebPages;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
    using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
    using System.Web.Optimization;
    using System.Web.Routing;
    using WebApplication1;


    public class _Page_Views_home_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<dynamic> {

#line hidden

        public _Page_Views_home_Index_cshtml() {
        }

        protected ASP.global_asax ApplicationInstance {
            get {
                return ((ASP.global_asax)(Context.ApplicationInstance));
            }
        }

        public override void Execute() {
BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 0, 4, true);

WriteLiteral("<div");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 0, 4, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 4, 18, true);

WriteLiteral(" class=\"jumbotron\"");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 4, 18, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 22, 31, true);

WriteLiteral(">\r\n    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>\r\n    <p");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 22, 31, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 53, 13, true);

WriteLiteral(" class=\"lead\"");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 53, 13, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 66, 130, true);

WriteLiteral(">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web application" +
"s using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.</p>\r\n    <p><a");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 66, 130, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 196, 22, true);

WriteLiteral(" href=\"http://asp.net\"");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 196, 22, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 218, 31, true);

WriteLiteral(" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-lg\"");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 218, 31, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 249, 41, true);

WriteLiteral(">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>\r\n</div>\r\n<div");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 249, 41, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 290, 12, true);

WriteLiteral(" class=\"row\"");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 290, 12, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 302, 11, true);

WriteLiteral(">\r\n    <div");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 302, 11, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 313, 17, true);

WriteLiteral(" class=\"col-md-4\"");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 313, 17, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 330, 359, true);

WriteLiteral(@">
        <h2>Getting started</h2>
        <p>
            ASP.NET Web API is a framework that makes it easy to build HTTP services that reach
            a broad range of clients, including browsers and mobile devices. ASP.NET Web API
            is an ideal platform for building RESTful applications on the .NET Framework.
        </p>
        <p><a");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 330, 359, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 689, 24, true);

WriteLiteral(" class=\"btn btn-default\"");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 689, 24, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 713, 53, true);

WriteLiteral(" href=\"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301870\"");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 713, 53, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 766, 49, true);

WriteLiteral(">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <div");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 766, 49, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 815, 17, true);

WriteLiteral(" class=\"col-md-4\"");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 815, 17, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 832, 202, true);

WriteLiteral(">\r\n        <h2>Get more libraries</h2>\r\n        <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio " +
"extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in V" +
"isual Studio projects.</p>\r\n        <p><a");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 832, 202, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1034, 24, true);

WriteLiteral(" class=\"btn btn-default\"");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1034, 24, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1058, 53, true);

WriteLiteral(" href=\"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301871\"");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1058, 53, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1111, 49, true);

WriteLiteral(">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <div");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1111, 49, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1160, 17, true);

WriteLiteral(" class=\"col-md-4\"");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1160, 17, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1177, 175, true);

WriteLiteral(">\r\n        <h2>Web Hosting</h2>\r\n        <p>You can easily find a web hosting com" +
"pany that offers the right mix of features and price for your applications.</p>\r" +
"\n        <p><a");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1177, 175, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1352, 24, true);

WriteLiteral(" class=\"btn btn-default\"");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1352, 24, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1376, 53, true);

WriteLiteral(" href=\"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301872\"");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1376, 53, true);

BeginContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1429, 51, true);

WriteLiteral(">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>\r\n    </div>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n");

EndContext("~/Views/home/Index.cshtml", 1429, 51, true);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It appears that something went wrong with adding the first view, when scaffolding. I did not check the web.config file inside the View folder, as it turned out, there was a namespace added, named WebApplication1. I have no idea how I did this, but after removing it, everything worked fine again.

So, if you ever get such error, check all your Web.Config files.

Comment: I renamed a namespace using the built-in function in Visual Studio which updates all references throughout the application but apparently it missed the line in the `Web.config` file inside the `Views` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the web.config solves this problem, had same as well, had to make a change in my web.config for the thing to get fixed.